# Django Rest Framework/Angular JS Preflight options request

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I've written an API using Django REST Framework. For authentication, I'm using django-oauth2-provider: https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider

I have cors configured in my settings page like so (using Corsheaders middleware.)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # Dangerous (using for testing purposes)
```

My client application is built with Angular JS. However, every time we make any request (including a GET requests), an options request is sent out. This options request takes ~50 - 500 ms depending on the request.

The api calls look like "https://example.com/api/v1/posts/?page=1 (2, 3, 4...etc)"

I need to wrap my head around why this request is being made, and how to improve performance for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [Two Strategies for Crossing Origins with Performance in Mind](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16408/Two-Strategies-for-Crossing-Origins-with-Performance-in-Mind/).

They boil down to:

1. Proper use of `Access-Control-Max-Age`
2. Staying within the confines of a "simple request"

Comment: what do you mean by confines of a simple request?

Comment: do I convert all requests coming from my frontend SPA(Angular/React/etc) into a simple request that does not do a CORS check.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE** setting to cache the responses:

> CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE: specify the number of seconds a client/browser can cache the preflight response

[This tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) explains the **Access-Control-Max-Age**:

> Access-Control-Max-Age (optional) - Making a preflight request on
>   *every* request becomes expensive, since the browser is making two
>   requests for every client request. The value of this header allows the
>   preflight response to be cached for a specified number of seconds.

Comment: Thanks David, I've looked into the CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE before, I've tried it and it didn't work. Also the default value is pretty high. 

Default: CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE = 86400

Answer (score 0):

when your server request preflight request your server should allow that request by responding back with proper headers
server shoud sent back the request with
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `Content-Type` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the browser from which the request is made. Because I am in control of both the server instance and the client, in my case I was able to set the request headers on the client to "text/plain" which takes care of the CORS preflight requirement.
Then, server-side I modified my rest_framework source to basically accept "text/plain" as a JSON media type.
Simple workaround, however, this may not be acceptable for everyone.